# how to find object 0 in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with a list of objects.

[image]

I would like to check when I am at 0 object so I can skip it and just process objects 1 through 7. My code does it, but I wanted to find out if there is a more elegant, shorter method of doing this.

```
function doSomething(array) {
    var list = [];                      
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
        if (i != 0) {                               
            list.push({
                name: array[i].name,
                last: array[i].last)
            });
        }           
    }
}
```

I decided to use the ng directive ng-if on the ng-repeat $index variable to skip the first element of the array.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-if="$index > 0">
```

So instead that using a for loop I use a forEach, that is the preferred technique in my workplace:

```
        function doSomething(array) {
        list = [];              
        array.forEach(
            function (arrayList) {              
                list.push({
                    name: arrayList.name,
                    last: arrayList.last
                    });
            });                 
        }
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: What does it mean to be "at" an object?

Comment: you could always start counting from 1

Comment: Start from 1 then!
for(var i = 1; i<payload.data.length; i++) {
     process(payload.data[i]);
}

Comment: I have updated my question, can it be placed out of hold? I have also found a solution, and rather than making a change in the loop, I am going to use a ng directive since it does well what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common `for` loop is easy for this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(i !== 0){
   // do stuff
  }
}
```

You could do this tons of different ways. You could even do

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Which offsets the whole count to start at array result 1

Comment: Have not tried it, but can I apply the ngif directive directly in the markup? like: <tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-if="$index > 0">

Comment: I believe that does work, sorry, i didn't see you were using angular. I know you can pass `$event` or `$index` into functions so you should be able to do what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shan